# Personally Identifiable Information (PII), Traces, and MessageLogging

Tags: .net, wcf, security, logging, serialization

[MSDN talks about how credit card information could accidentally be logged during traces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  But that same article explains that "known" Personally Identifiable Information is not logged.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to 'flag' members of a DataContract as PII, to take advantage of the .net built-on capability of filtering out PII from traces and logs?  I'm thinking the answer is "no," because the user names and passwords the article references I suspect are part of authentication steps, rather than part of data contracts that follow authentication.

Even so, is there any kind of built-in .net attribute I can annotate a Data Contract or serializeable class members with, which means "hey, this is a security sensitive attribute, beware!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the below blog that explains how to add [PII] attribute to data contract

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2008/08/18/suppressing-personal-identifiable-information-pii-in-wcf-log-files.aspx

Comment: Since the link is dead, [here's the only snapshot from the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140421090323/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2008/08/18/suppressing-personal-identifiable-information-pii-in-wcf-log-files.aspx)