# How to remove PII from Logs in WCF (svclog)?

Tags: .net, wcf, security, privacy

This is directly related to the question
[Personally Identifiable Information (PII), Traces, and MessageLogging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547687/personally-identifiable-information-pii-traces-and-messagelogging). I've tried the solution in the answer but here are the problems I found.

1. It doesn't remove the PII (Personal Identifiable Information) from the response, only in the request.
2. It doesn't support MessageContracts / MessageBodyMember.

It might be just that the code just really doesn't cover this or I'm missing some configuration. If anyone has a solid solution to making sure that the traces in the svclog doesn't contain fields that I mark as PII, whether they are datacontract or messagecontract?

Here is the updated code from the answer in the related post https://github.com/janmchan/PiiFilter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like the solution is to create a custom trace listener. The default wcf Pii masking is there for masking default known pii but for very specific fields, the custom trace listener would need to intercept how the message itself is logged.

Here is a demo of the custom trace listener I've made.
https://github.com/janmchan/CustomTraceListener